# cassandra query string access

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Using [Cassandra triggers](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-2-0-prototype-triggers-support), is it possible to get the `query string` that was fired?
`ITrigger`'s `augment` method has key and ColumnFamily inputs. This interface is not helping to capture the query string. How do I get the query string such as `insert into blah blah` programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Using Cassandra triggers, is it possible to get the query string that was fired?

Not really since mutations don't have access to the query string.

If you want to see the query being executed you can modify `o.a.c.cql3.QueryProcessor` where you have access to the query string. For arbitrary string executions you'll want `process(...)` but for prepared statements it's a bit more complicated. You have access to the prepared statement's query string at the time where it's prepared (created and stored) in the `storePreparedStatement(...)` function. To see the values that are being bound to a statement you'll have to check `processStatement(...)`'s variables which is a collection of ByteBuffers.

Take a look at [CASSANDRA-6572](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6572) for more details.